# Unmet dependency error when trying to install react-native-cli using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

When I run

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

I see this error

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/readdir-scoped-modules requires graceful-fs@'^4.1.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.8
```

I've tried updating graceful-fs by

```
npm update -g graceful-fs
```

Reacts website suggests using `sudo` if you have a permission error. This error doesn't seem permission related but if it is, I can certainly run `sudo`.

I'm an npm and node noob so please ask for any more info that will help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `npm update -g` and then was able to install the React CLI.